# Upgrading Django 1.3 to 1.4 raising Unicode problems

Tags: python, django, unicode, upgrade

I'm having a hard time upgrading Django 1.3.x to Django 1.4.x. The development server in the 1.4 version doesn't allow the following code:

```
print unicode("Nº")
```

The 1.3 works fine but the 1.4 gives the legendary decoding error:

```
'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xc2 in position 1: ordinal not in range(128)
```

Why is that? Is there any configuration of how the decoding will be handled?

Note: The print statement is just a simple way of showing the problem, in the real legacy application there are tons of code that send an non-unicode string to the `unicode` function.

Comment: If you are upgrading, you should upgrade to django 1.8 django 1.4 is unsupported since Last year october. Even if you upgrade to 1.4 you will have to upgrade to 1.8 sooner or later so that's going to be twice the effort.

Comment: Indeed, but im doing it in small steps, it seems easier to do this way.

Answer (score 1):

So there are probably a couple issues coming up with this. The first is `print unicode("string")` is taking that string as a straight non unicode string (assuming this is python 2.7). If you change it to `print unicode(u"Nº")` does it work?

Between that and calling `.encode('UTF-8')` / `decode('UTF-8')` in places where you need it should help. Dealing with unicode in Python 2 is kinda painful. There's been a LOT of talks about unicode at various PyCons many of which have been posted to youtube. If you have an hour or it's worth watching https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sgHbC6udIqc and https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Mx70n1dL534

From the sounds of it you may just need to go through and check that every source of every string you're dealing with is being converted to a unicode object via decode('utf-8') or whatever the encoding is, as soon as possible. Alternatively if you can skip straight to a later version of Django (everything before 1.8 at this time has zero support) you might be able to use something like 2to3 to change to Python3, and as a side effect get rid of a lot of these types of problems. Not always feasible but worth a shot =)

Comment: Changing to u"Nº" indeed does work, but as you may imagine it seems a bit dangerous to change all strings of the legacy system with the u'' version. The strange thing from my point of view is why changing the webserver version the behaviour of decoding (which I supposed to be role of the language itself not the framework). Strangely enough, running the app with `gunicorn_django` instead doesn't make the error happen. I'll give a look in those videos now, thanks. :)